# what syntax would i use to query the whole database?

Tags: mysql

I would like to select a row from 2 different tables that are relational. 
Would i simply put

```
SELECT * FROM 'said database' WHERE my condition = 'mycondition' blah blah.
```

Or is it some other syntactical method?

Please help. :)

All answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (roughly) will do the trick for you.

```
select <data> from table1
inner join table2 on table1.column = table2.column
where <mycondition>
```

Learn more about joins from the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA A INNER JOIN Table B ON A.Id = B.Id WHERE condition = 'mycondition'
```

Comment: Thank You 37starz! Stack Overflow is just awesome, Just to clarify the dots are part of the syntax? ive never used those in sql before.

Answer (score 2):

It would need to be something like:

```
Select * from Table1 inner Join Table2 ON Table1.field_condition_from_table_1 = Table2 .field_condition_from_table_2 where Table1.condition_from_table_1 = "your_condition"
```

And that will do the trick. There's other ways you can do it, but this way will bring whatever you need in common from the two tables

Answer (score 0):

Comprehensive join syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).